# puppeteer - get complete x Path of an element handle

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

Is there a way to retrieve **complete xpath** of an *element handle* using puppeteer ?

Note - I'm NOT asking about page.$x('specific_x_path') method. Instead I'm asking about the opposite of it.

i.e. I have identified the element handle using classes and other data set and would like to use puppeteer to retrieve it's complete XPATH in the DOM tree.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this can help, but I've asked about it in DevTools protocol repository (https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/issues/158) and was advised to reimplement this from source code of DevTools context menu command for XPath copy (it seems the file is now here: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/elements/DOMPath.js).

Comment: Thanks @vsemozhetbyt. I'll spend some time with it to see if I can get this working.